# How to use both mathcal and pazocal in the same document

Tags: math-mode, mathpazo, calligraphy

I want to use different calligraphic versions, `mathcal` and `pazocal`, of some letters in the same project. However, when I add the `pazocal` package, even mathcal letters show up in the `pazocal` format. Is there a way to use both styles for different letters in the same document?

-RD

Comment: What's `pazocal`? I don't see it on CTAN

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: @egreg My link is your old answer.

Comment: `pazocal` is not a package.